# Diffusion equation in energy and magnetic surface coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, diffusion

The [isotropic diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation#Statement) in Cartesian coordinates is

$$\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial t}=\nabla[D(f,\mathbf{x})\nabla f(\mathbf{x},t)]$$

[Boozer and Kuo‐Petravic (1981)](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.863445) claim that with a diffusion coefficient defined as $D(E,\psi)$ for particles of energy $E$ and radial position $\psi$ (also called *constant magnetic surface coordinate*), the diffusion equation is given by

$$\frac{\partial f(E,\psi)}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{s(\psi)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi}\left(D(E,\psi)s(\psi)\frac{\partial f(E,\psi)}{\partial\psi}\right)$$

where $s(\psi)$ is the defined so the volume element of physical space is $d^3x=s(\psi)d\psi$.

How do you transform the equation from Cartesian coordinates to this new $(E,\psi)$ coordinate system?

Comment: It seems like they just used the formula for the divergence in general coordinates: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#General_coordinates). They assume no dependence different from the radial $\psi$ which explains the single $\partial_\psi$ derivative both in the divergence and in the gradient.

Comment: so, they are defining $s(\psi)$ as the Jacobian determinant of the transformation, then $\sqrt{det(g)}=s(\psi)$?

Comment: That seems to be the case. I assume in the question you are skipping some coordinates in $d^3x$. I'd expect $d^3x=s(\psi) \, d\psi \, dy_1 \, dy_2$ with $y_1$ and $y_2$ some other 2 coordinates.

Comment: It is written like that in the paper, actually they don't explicitly say which are the new variables, but I assume that the missing ones must be the toroidal $\phi$ and the poloidal $\psi$...

Comment: In an azimuthally symmetric dipole one can define a coordinate system where your radial position is determined by a constant magnetic pressure.  It's not an orthonormal basis by any means or even an orthogonal coordinate system.  You use the dipole equation as a map to go back and forth between cartesian and this curvilinear system.  The azimuthal and poloidal angles are included in their Jacobian but the I think they are only interested in radial diffusion, which is why they setup a 1D diffusion equation.